# How to initialize objects specific to request/context

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have Apache CXF, JAX-RS based webservice project. I have implemented role based authentication/authorization. Upon authentication If user is authenticated, I want to use this  object ( user object) to use across the project for access logging or "who did what" purpose.
Is there any way to do this? Also this object should be request based. Because every request is authenticated to DB.

Here is sample code.

```
 public class SecurityInterceptor implements RequestHandler {

@Override
public Response handleRequest(Message message,  ClassResourceInfo classResourceInfo) {

    Response response = null;

    OperationResourceInfo operationResourceInfo = message.getExchange().get(OperationResourceInfo.class);
    Method methodToInvoke = operationResourceInfo.getMethodToInvoke();

    if ( methodToInvoke.isAnnotationPresent(AllowAll.class) ){//Allow all the request to pass. i.e. login,menu_item etc.
        response = null;
    } else if ( methodToInvoke.isAnnotationPresent(RolesAllowed.class) ){ // authenticate and authorize.

        Map<String, List<String> > valueMap = ((Map<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS));
        List<String> tokenList = valueMap.get(TOKEN_HEADER);

        //checking whether token list is empty.
        if ( tokenList == null || tokenList.isEmpty() ){
            response = Response.ok( prepareResponse(FAILURE , _00028 ) ).build(); 
        } else { //else authenticate request with token .
            String token = tokenList.get(0);

            AuthenticationBO authBo = new AuthenticationBOImpl();
            authBo.authenticate(token);
            if ( authBo.getResponse().getStatus() == SUCCESS ){

                Authentication auth = authBo.getResponse().getPbBeans().getAuthentication();

                //this user object needs to be set in Context to be used in service classes.
                final User contextUser = auth.getUser();

                Set<Integer> rolesSet = new HashSet<Integer>(  Arrays.asList( ArrayUtils.toObject(methodToInvoke.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class).value() ) ) );

                if ( !authorize( contextUser , rolesSet ) ){
                    response = Response.ok( prepareResponse(FAILURE , _00022 ) ).build() ;  
                } else {

                    authBo = new AuthenticationBOImpl();
                    authBo.updateLastAccessTime( token );
                    if ( authBo.getResponse().getStatus() == FAILURE ){
                        System.out.println(" AUTHENTICATION UPDATE FAILURE !!! ");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                response = Response.ok( prepareResponse(authBo.getResponse().getStatus() , authBo.getResponse().getCode())).build();
            }   
        }
    }
    return response;
}

private boolean authorize(User user , Set<Integer> rolesAllowed ){
    if ( rolesAllowed.contains( user.getUser_role_key() )  ){
        return true ;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public PBResponse prepareResponse(Integer status, String code  ){

    PBResponse response = new PBResponse();
    response.setStatus(status);
    response.setCode(code);
    response.setMessage( CodeProperties.getInstance().getValue(code) );

    return response;
}
```

}

Comment: "I have implemented role based authentication/authorization" How? Show us the code.

Comment: Using Basic Authentication, I have implemented interceptor in CXF and from there I am using DB to authenticate the user by decoding using Base 64.

Comment: Please show us your code.